# Hide ykeys but show label on morris js

Tags: morris.js

could you help me with this problem? I have this graphic in morris js where I show 2 variables, what I need is to generate a label of the sum without it being graphed.

```
  Morris.Bar({
    element: 'bar-example2',
    data: [     
 { y: '2018-05-21', a: 0, b: 8472, c: 8472 },          
 { y: '2018-05-20', a: 0,  b: 8391, c: 20 },         
 { y: '2018-05-19', a: 0,  b: 9031, c: 9031 },          
 { y: '2018-05-18', a: 0,  b: 8974, c: 8974 },          
 { y: '2018-05-17', a: 360,  b: 9095, c: 9455 },         
 { y: '2018-05-16', a: 0,  b: 10017, c: 10017 },
 { y: '2018-05-15', a: 0, b: 9576, c: 9576 }

    ],
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['a','b','c'],
    labels: ['Mot1', 'Mot2', 'Total'],
    stacked: true
    });
```

I have this

[image: Example of current chart output]

I want this

[image: Example of wanted chart output]

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the function `hoverCallback` in the options to customize its content. The following code should do the job:

```
  hoverCallback: function (index, options, content, row) {
    console.log(row);
    return 'Your value is: '+parseFloat(row.a+row.b);
  },
```

You can check the help here: http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/bars.html